# When appending elements in the list in python, using the for loop it returns only the result of the first iteration

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, pagination

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException, NoSuchElementException
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import urllib
import time
import pandas
import re
driver_service = Service(executable_path=ChromeDriverManager().install())
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=driver_service)
driver.get("https://www.rataindia.com/vendor-listing.php?page=")

# paste url that you want to scrape

wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
try:
    driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();",wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CLASS_NAME, "close-button"))))
except:
    pass
siteData = []
for nav in range(1,82,1):
    for i in range(1,2,1):
       # listing = driver.find_element(By.ID,'vendor-block')
       
        listing = driver.find_elements(By.ID, "vendor-block")
        lists = listing.find_elements(By.XPATH, "/html/body/section[2]/div/div/div/div["+ str(i) +"]/a")
        for listss in lists:
            time.sleep(2) # wait 2 seconds
            try:
                name = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,'//*[@id="vendor-block"]/div/div[1]/div/div/a/div/div[2]').text
                print(name)
            except:
                pass
            try:
                 address = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,'//*[@id="vendor-block"]/div/div[1]/div/div/a/div/div[3]').text
                 print(address)
                
                
            except:
                pass
            
            time.sleep(2)  #wait for 2 minutes


           
           
               
            
            
        
       
       #append the data 


        siteData.append({"company":name, "address":address})
        df = pandas.DataFrame(siteData)
        df.to_csv("rataindia12.csv")

        #next page click
        
    driver.find_element(By.XPATH,'//*[@id="vendor-block"]/div/div[2]/div/ul/li/a/span[contains(@class, "hidden-xs") and text()="Next"]').click()
```

When appending elements in the list in python, using the for loop it returns only the result of the first iteration

I am trying to scrap the website listing data in excel sheet and it returns only the first iteration value in every page using for loop. Please help me out for this

Comment: please help me for this. its returns every page first listing value

Comment: youre overwriting `name` and `address` value every time. Its a single value after the for cycle. It can also fail after the first iteration, but you will not see that cuz you used except: pass statement. Usually you would need to print the exception at the very least.

Comment: I tried but it not giving me any error

Comment: C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps\python3.10.exe: can't open file 'C:\\Python311\\Untitled-2': [Errno 2] No such file or directory 
it giving me the above error

Comment: this error is not selenium related. Ask a new question with relevant tags and info

Comment: ok but tried but no error is coming now and its return first value every time. can you help me to show any example

Comment: ive said that youre overwriting the values. if you have tried that please update the original post then.

Comment: for listss in lists:
          
            time.sleep(2)
            try:
                name =  listss.find_element(By.XPATH,'//*[@id="vendor-block"]/div/div[1]/div/div/a/div/div[2]').text
                print(name)
            
                address =  listss.find_element(By.XPATH,'//*[@id="vendor-block"]/div/div[1]/div/div/a/div/div[3]').text
                print(address)
            except Exception as e:
                
                print(e)

Comment: oh you changed nothing. `address = listss.find_element(By.XPATH,'//*[@id="vendor-block"]/div/div[1]/div/div/a/div/div[3]').text` this line gets repeated and address in this case is a single string. you overwrite it every iteration. im not going to launch the script or write code for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code has some problems, the most serious one is that at each loop you are overwriting `name` and `address`. What you have to do is to initialize a list or a dictionary before entering the loop, and then at each loop add values to it. Even better, you can remove the nested loops and get all the values in the page with list comprehension (for example `[x.text for in x driver.find_elements(...)]`).

```
data = {key:[] for key in ['name','address']}
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)

while 1:
    
    print(f'current page: {driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, "current").text}', end='\r')
    
    data['name']    += [x.text                     for x in wait.until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.CLASS_NAME, 'v-logo')))]
    data['address'] += [x.text.replace('\n',' - ') for x in wait.until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.CLASS_NAME, 'v-name')))]

    next_btn = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//span[text()='Next']")
    next_btn_disabled = next_btn.find_element(By.XPATH, './ancestor::li').get_attribute('class') == 'disabled'
    if next_btn_disabled:
        print('\nNo more pages')
        break
    else:
        next_btn.click()

import pandas as pd
pd.DataFrame(data)
```

Output

[image]